Bulk Update using array of option fields on mysql database and php
The problem I am having is that the exact row changes is not updating the intended row but a row before the row. So if I make changes to row 45 and 46 respectively. I will see the update on row 44 and 45
This is the post onclick the submit button
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['id']);$i++){
        $id=$_POST['id'][$i];
        $status=$_POST['status'][$i];
        $update = mysqli_query ($link,"UPDATE mgt_checklist_breakdown SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '$id'");
    }
}

This is the html table which contains the array of dropdown select to update mysql
<?php 
    $a = mysqli_query($link,"select * from mgt_checklist_breakdown where checklist_id='$_GET[id]'"); 
    while ($fa=mysqli_fetch_assoc($a)){
        $i++;
?> 

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $fa['sn'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fa['checklist'];?></td>
    <td>
        <select name="status[]" class="form-select">
            <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
            <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $fa['id'];?>">
    </td>
</tr>
<?php 
    } 
?>


Why are you not using prepared statements to handle the db updates? Your code is open to SQL injection as it is. Incidentally the hidden input was not at a valid location in the HTML so it was moved to within a table cell

The update statement could be executed just once if you were to use a different syntax that uses a where id in (range,of,values) type approach

Could you please assist with a code to help me understand your input

The general structure of the query should be UPDATE tablename SET status = CASE id WHEN id1 THEN status1 WHEN id2 THEN status2 WHEN id3 THEN status3 ... END WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3, ...)

You should be able to construct that query dynamically from the array of form parameters.

I'd use <select name="status[<?php echo $fa['id'];?>]" to begin with, and do away with the hidden input field. Then you can do sth. like foreach($_POST['status'] as $id => $statusValue), and don't have to correlate with an extra loop counter.

First you need to wrap the table in form tag with the method Post
And then after closing table tag you to create a submit button inside form tag .
After that you have run your php update script:-
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$ids = $_POST['id'];
$stat = $_POST['status'];

// Iteration
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $ids[$i]);
    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $stat[$i]);

    // update query
    $upd = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE mgt_checklist_breakdown SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '$id'");

    // Check errors
    if (!$upd) {
        echo "Error updating record with ID $id: " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}

}

Please stop using mysqli_real_escape_string! Use prepared statements!
